# How do I disable the default syndaemon?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

By default, syndaemon is called with `-i 2.0 -K -R -t`. This runs automatically on startup. In previous ubuntus, you could go to the mouse settings and disable the "disable mouse on typing" option, but now in ubuntu 15+, that option seems to have been removed.

How can I disable the default calling of syndaemon so I can run my own non-bugged command in its place?

I should add that this has been prevoiusly reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1215463).

I have tried putting this in startup applications: `sleep 30; killall syndaemon; syndaemon -i .5 -K -R -d`, but it doesn't work. I have also tried putting that line in my .profile, but syndaemon seems to be launched after .profile loads.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: If you have an alternative program file and root access, one common solution would be make '/usr/bin/syndaemon'  permission to not executable .

Comment: Well, I'm using Ubuntu and here no `syndaemon` is running!

Comment: @anwar are you running 15+? If you are running less than 15, do you have disable mouse on typing checked?

Comment: @Anwar you have to be on a laptop right? My touchpad moves the cursor too with palm movement which is annoying but I use a wireless keyboard and mouse  99.999% of the time so never cared until I read this question.

Comment: @f41lurizer what laptop make and model are you using?

Comment: @f41lurizer Enter `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` in the Terminal and update your question with the output.

Answer (score 2):

first find the syndaemon executable

```
which syndaemon
```

then find which package owns it

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/syndaemon
```

then list the contents of the package that owns it

```
dpkg -L xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

have a look at the .conf files listed and you will see 
the settings you can change.

If you can't find the options you want in there try reading the manual
pages listed , these are anything in /usr/share/man and you can view them as follows

```
man 4 synaptics
```

This was tested on ubuntu 16.04 and shouldn't be different for other versions

Comment: in my conf files i can see several options relating to palm detection and disable while typing options.

Comment: this will be systemd service in version newer than 18.X

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was right, but the command needs to be a little different:

`sh -c "sleep 30; killall syndaemon; syndaemon -i .5 -K -R -d"`

This solved the issue for me.